# How to use external repository in kscript (Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin

What are correct way to get kscript to load jdbc from external maven repository?

I have in the start of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript
@file:DependsOn("oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1")
@file:MavenRepository("infosynergi","http://maven.infosynergi.no" )

import java.sql.*
```

I get this error:

> [kscript] Resolving dependencies... [kscript]     Resolving
>   oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1...Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSException
>           at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:177)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.getDefaultProvider(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:246)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.getProvider(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:241)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnector.(AsyncRepositoryConnector.java:154)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.connector.async.AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:106)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:346)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
>           at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
>           at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:191)
>           at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:333)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.fetch(Aether.java:228)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.resolve_aroundBody2(Aether.java:180)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether$AjcClosure3.run(Aether.java:1)
>           at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrap(MethodLogger.java:208)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$wrap(MethodLogger.java:1)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapClass(MethodLogger.java:136)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.resolve(Aether.java:177)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.resolve_aroundBody0(Aether.java:163)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether$AjcClosure1.run(Aether.java:1)
>           at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrap(MethodLogger.java:208)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$com_jcabi_aspects_aj_MethodLogger$wrap(MethodLogger.java:1)
>           at com.jcabi.aspects.aj.MethodLogger.wrapClass(MethodLogger.java:136)
>           at com.jcabi.aether.Aether.resolve(Aether.java:156)
>           at kscript.app.DependencyUtilKt.resolveDependenciesViaAether(DependencyUtil.kt:77)
>           at kscript.app.DependencyUtilKt.resolveDependencies(DependencyUtil.kt:51)
>           at kscript.app.KscriptKt.main(Kscript.kt:158)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.AbstractRunner.run(runners.kt:61)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.run(Main.kt:109)
>           at org.jetbrains.kotlin.runner.Main.main(Main.kt:119) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException
>           at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 38 more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is correct. It's a known bug in kscript, see https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript/issues/239. The only workaround at the moment is to use java8.

**Update**
This problem was fixed in kscript v3.0

Comment: Actually I switched to using Go :-P.