# How do you resolve a 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' when importing libraries in Kscript?

Tags: maven, kotlin, kotlin-script

I'm new to Kotlin scripting, and I'm trying to use Kscript to import libraries. I've been following the tutorials, and trying a very simple script (below) that imports a couple libraries. When I go to run the script, I get the below error (this error happens with any import I try to do). The script runs fine when I remove the imports. Any ideas on how I can fix the imports in my code?

Error message:

```
[kscript] Resolving dependencies...
[kscript]     Resolving org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ietf/jgss/GSSException
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

@file:MavenRepository("central", "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/")
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2")
@file:DependsOn("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.3.2")

import kotlinx.coroutines.*

println("Script is running with ${args.size} args passed")

for(arg in args) {
    println("arg: $arg")
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57254118/how-to-use-external-repository-in-kscript-kotlin

Comment: That did it @josepraveen! Thank you

Comment: did you solve this issue by using jdk 1.8?

Comment: Yes. Can you please add it as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script fails when you use jdk 9+ and  causes the NoClassDefFoundError for `org/ietf/jgss/GSSException` on Kotlin 1.3.x.

**As a workaround use jdk 1.8.**

Future fix refer this [Dependencies are working only with jdk8](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript/issues/239)